# Keeping dimensions of a plane when twisting

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am following this youtube tutorial on making a mobius strip:

https://www.google.com/search?q=mobius+strip+blender+&sca_esv=d310bf87f451f94c&rlz=1C5CHFA_enAU853AU853&sxsrf=ACQVn09J8sx5J30lDjf4G8sQyRl0KsbYwg%3A1711673929553&ei=SRIGZrC5IfbcseMP1-W62Ag&ved=0ahUKEwjwgaukopiFAxV2bmwGHdeyDosQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=mobius+strip+blender+&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiFW1vYml1cyBzdHJpcCBibGVuZGVyIDIGEAAYFhgeMgsQABiABBiKBRiGAzILEAAYgAQYigUYhgMyCxAAGIAEGIoFGIYDMgsQABiABBiKBRiGA0jJJFCCBVjZInABeAGQAQCYAa0BoAHRC6oBAzAuObgBA8gBAPgBAZgCCqAC8AvCAgoQABhHGNYEGLADwgINEAAYgAQYigUYQxiwA8ICChAAGIAEGIoFGEPCAgUQABiABMICBRAuGIAEwgILEAAYgAQYigUYkQKYAwCIBgGQBgqSBwMxLjmgB_Uj&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:a36232ed,vid:deIyUny6s2A,st:0

When I get to the part where I need to use a simple deform twist on the plane, the plane does not keep its dimensions when it twists, but completely stretches as it twists:

[image]

Help Please!

Thank you

Comment: Maybe the scale of your object isn't 1 ? Then Ctrl+A > *Apply Scale*. Consider uploading your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/.

Comment: the link to the tutorial in your question is actually a google search and just displays a result list.